# Moving from 64-bit Amazon EC2 instance to 32-bit instance, keeping filesystem intact

Tags: amazon-ec2, 32bit-64bit

I've set up my web application on a Micro EC2 instance, and have spent quite some time installing necessary software and files. Now, I want my same setup but on a High CPU Medium instance. However, the High CPU Medium instance only supports 32-bit OS, whereas my Micro instance is currently 64-bit, so I can't even attach my 64-bit EBS volume to the 32-bit instance's root.

**How can I copy my setup over to the 32-bit instance without having to reinstall everything?**

Comment: I'm not aware that there is a way to convert between 32 bit and 64 bit instances because software must be compiled accordingly, but generally you can convert between different sized instances using EC2 command line tools, eg.: ec2-modify-instance-attribute -K pk-....pem -C cert-....pem -v i-INSTANCEID --region eu-west-1 -instance-type m1.small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS is this? You very likely have 64-bit binaries installed, so you can't simply rsync/copy over the root ('/') from one instance to the other. If you installed packages using yum or apt, you should be able to do something like this:

1. Start the new c1.medium instance
2. Install the exact same packages using the package manager, which will pull in 32-bit binaries
3. rsync/copy over /etc/ and any other text configuration files over
4. dump your db and reimport into the db running on your c1.medium instance

However, I wouldn't recommend using c1.medium. If you ever need to grow, you're going to be forced to do the 32-bit -> 64-bit migration in the future. This is potentially much easier, as 32-bit binaries will run on a 64-bit system, but you might as well save yourself some time now and just jump to a m1.large. Unfortunately Amazon doesn't have anything in between, in terms of RAM.

Comment: It's a shame EC2 still doesn't have an 64-bit Small available. Even the Medium is gone now. So, if we want to run a light LAMP app our only option is to use Small with an ELB, and start multiple instances when scaling is needed. This seriuously complicates the design of the app.